# UTF-8 not useful to display quotes and foreign characters in this text

Tags: php, curl

I retrieve text from a php site using curl like this:

```
$ctitlece = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=comment_t&lang=AM';
$cauthce = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=comment_a&lang=AM';
$csrcce = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=comment_s&lang=AM';
$creadce = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=comment&lang=AM';

if ( $curl_exists ) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ctitlece);        
    $titlece = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cauthce);      
    $authce = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $csrcce);          
    $srcce = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $creadce);      
    $readce = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Then I show it on my web page like this:

```
<span class="readings_heading">Commentary</span><br/>
<div class="rscroll">
    <div class='rtitlec'>
    <?php echo $titlece; ?>
    </div>
    <div class='rtitlec'>
    <?php echo $authce; ?>
    </div>
    <div class='rtitlec'>
    <?php echo $srcce; ?>
    </div>
    <span class="line_space"></span>
    <div id='readce' class='rtextc'>
    <?php echo $readce; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I have the main page character set as UTF-8, the quotes still come up as weird characters.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

[image: Strange characters in text]

If I do a utf-8 decode

```
$readce_before = curl_exec($ch);
$readce = utf8_decode ( $readce_before );
```

this removes the diamonds, but still prints question marks instead of the quotes.

The original page that I read in the curl is plain html like this:

```
<font style="align-text:left" dir="ltr">The joy of the gospel fills the hearts and lives of all who encounter Jesus. Those who accept his offer of salvation are set free from sin, sorrow, inner emptiness and loneliness. With Christ joy is constantly born anew... The great danger in today’s world, pervaded as it is by consumerism, is the desolation and anguish born of a complacent yet covetous heart, the feverish pursuit of frivolous pleasures, and a blunted conscience. Whenever our interior life becomes caught up in its own interests and concerns, there is no longer room for others, no place for the poor. God’s voice is no longer heard... This is a very real danger for believers too... I invite all Christians, everywhere, at this very moment, to a renewed personal encounter with Jesus Christ, or at least an openness to letting him encounter them; I ask all of you to do this unfailingly each day. No one should think that this invitation is not meant for him or her, since “no one is excluded from the joy brought by the Lord” (Pope Paul VI). The Lord does not disappoint those who take this risk; whenever we take a step towards Jesus, we come to realize that he is already there, waiting for us with open arms. Now is the time to say to Jesus: “Lord, I have let myself be deceived; in a thousand ways I have shunned your love, yet here I am once more, to renew my covenant with you. I need you. Save me once again, Lord, take me once more into your redeeming embrace”. How good it feels to come back to him whenever we are lost!... God never tires of forgiving us; we are the ones who tire of seeking his mercy. Christ, who told us to forgive one another “seventy times seven” (Mt 18,2) has given us his example... Time and time again he bears us on his shoulders (Lk 15,5). No one can strip us of the dignity bestowed upon us by this boundless and unfailing love. With a tenderness which never disappoints, but is always capable of restoring our joy, he makes it possible for us to lift up our heads and to start anew.</font><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://dailygospel.org" target="_blank">dailygospel.org</a>
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found. When the php information is shown using JQ .load the weird characters are shown.

```
    $('#commentary').load('commenglish.php?readings_date='+readings_date+'&readings_hour='+readings_hour, function() {
```

Switching to a static div with the same information from the php shows the right encoding.

```
<div id="commentary" style="width: 98%; height: 100%; min-width: 300px; position: relative; top: 0px; padding: 8px 3px 3px 3px; overflow:hidden; background:white; font: 0.9em arial, sans-serif;">
    <?php $readings_date=$_REQUEST['readings_date']; $readings_hour=$_REQUEST['readings_hour']; require("commenglish.php"); ?>      
    <?php $readings_date=$_REQUEST['readings_date']; $readings_hour=$_REQUEST['readings_hour']; require("commfrench.php"); ?>       
    <?php $readings_date=$_REQUEST['readings_date']; $readings_hour=$_REQUEST['readings_hour']; require("commspanish.php"); ?>      
</div> <!-- End Commentary -->
```

This works with a meta tag with ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 3):

The original data is returned in `ISO-8859-1`, while you're trying to output it as-is in `UTF-8`. That is wrong.

You have to re-encode it into `UTF-8` using [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/utf8_encode) or [`iconv()`](http://php.net/iconv) whichever you like more.

Comment: Originally I had ISO-8859-1 but this showed the weird characters.  The combination UTF-8 with utf8_decode showed question marks instead of the weird characters. If I just print the text as returned it with the ISO-8859-1 it prints the weird characters.

Comment: @user823527: `echo utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date=20140407&type=comment_s&lang=AM'));` works fine for me. You must be doing some additional conversion somewhere else.

Comment: This looks ok, but instead of showing the quotes it doesn't show that character at all.  For `today's` it shows `todays`.

Comment: @user823527: as I already mentioned - it works fine for me. Create a one line file with the code I gave above and check yourself.

Comment: The original text looks ok. But the code I have above with ISO-8859-1 doesn't show the quotes or the foreign accents.  UTF-8 doesn't do it either.  Is the issue with the meta line? is there a different set that I should be using?

Comment: @user823527: it should be fine and it works for me (I say that for the 3rd time already :-( )

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
iso-8859-1
```

Replace yours:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

with:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

It should work!

Comment: What was there before was ISO-8859-1.  This showed the strange characters.